# Difference between variable and object

Tags: c#, .net

Well, There are two statements occurred repeatedly in tutorials from where I'm learning C#.net

`DataRow dr;`

What does this mean. I assume it is a variable of `DataRow` class.

`DataRow dr = new DataRow();`

What does this mean. I assume it is an object of `DataRow` Class.

But still I left with an ambiguity that In which case I've to use 1st case Or 2nd Case. I'm quite confused now.

I assumed that this question has been repeated in Java forum. but I didn't get it as I don't have any background of Java. so before marking it repeat consider this.

Comment: What does Java have to do with your question?

Comment: There is a same question in Java. so before any one marked it repeated I prefer to make them warned.

Comment: Well, the answers will be the same as Java...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a variable has 2 parts, ***Declaration*** and ***Assignment***.

In the *Declaration* part, you state that the variable exists and you state its type:

```
DataRow dr; // Create's a variable of type DataRow with a value of null.
```

The *Assignment* takes a value and point the variable to it:

```
dr = new DataRow(); // Creates a new DataRow and points dr variable to it.
```

You can do them both in the same line like that:

```
DataRow dr = new DataRow();
```

The result is the same as if you would separate those into the 2 lines above and the type of the variable is in both cases `DataRow`.

The `object` inside the variable however can be of an inherited type:

```
class MyDataRow : DataRow
{
}

DataRow dr = new MyDataRow(); //Creates a new object of type MyDataRow and points dr to it.
```

Managed `objects` must be held by a variable otherwise they are [*Garbage Collected*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)).

Comment: Perfect. but in which case I've to used which one ?

Comment: You always *declare* and when you need to *assign* just do it. If you can do it in one line it's better for readabillity in my opinion.

Comment: By the way, you can instantiate without assigning: `new MyClass();` can stand on its own.

Comment: This will most likely be optimized away and if not it will be GCed.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in C#, like in most other languages, are places to store something in. Think of them as specially shaped drawers that you can fit exactly one thing in. Things to fit such a drawer are values.

C# essentially has two basic kinds of values: "value type" values and object references. (Let's ignore "pointers" for now.)

A "value type" is anything that C# defines as a `struct` or `enum`, which includes basic types such as `int`, `bool`, `char` or `double`. These values are directly stored in a variable, and if you use the variable in any way, the value is copied to where it's used (e.g. assigned to a new variable, or passed as argument to some method or operator).

All types in C# that not a value type are "reference types", which includes arrays, strings and most other classes. Instances of a reference type are not stored in variables, but reside in a special memory area called "heap". When you "assign and object to a variable", you actually only put a reference to that object into the variable. When accessing the variable, C# follows the reference to allow access to the object's members. In other words, the "value" of a reference type is just the reference to the object. So, when you pass the variable's content to some operator or method or assign it to some other variable, you only copy the reference, not the object behind it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow dr;
```

Is creating a variable with the type of DataRow but it will be null.

```
DataRow dr = new DataRow();
```

Is creating a variable and assigning it with a new value which in this case is an instance of a DataRow.

Answer (score 0):

In C# a DataRow can never be instantiated. It can always be used either as

DataTable dt=new DataTable();
DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();

This above statement creates a new row for the the table.

```
   DataRow dr=dt.Rows[0];
```

This above statement gets the first row from the datatable.

The below statement will never execute when compiled.

```
  DataRow dr=new DataRow();
```

[image: Error Screenshot on compilation]

Comment: Yeah after compilation I received it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow dr;
```

This basiclay tells dr is a variable of "type" DataRow. it does NOT create the DataRow Object itself.

```
**DataRow dr = new DataRow();**
```

This actually creates the object and stores it into "dr" variable.

You could write it like this...

```
DataRow dr;
dr = new DataRow();
```

notice at second line, I already knew "dr" is of type DataRow.

if you want to call any function of Datarow, then first you MUST create a instance of it..instances are created by using the "new" keyword.

Comment: and When to prefer which one ?

Comment: User preference i think the compiler will end up with the same thing in the end... I think..

Comment: DataRow dr; will do nothing unless you create a instance of it by doing new DataRow(). you need to study the concept of "objects / classes" in c# to get the whole idea.